# custom search query database in child theme

Tags: php, database, forms

I am trying to display searched data from database in wordpress child theme.

It does work on localhost but when I apply the code in wordpress only

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\testsite\wp-content\themes\twentyseventeen-child\custom-search-page.php on line 76.

Please help me solve this. Its been one week i have been doing research to solve this.

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
        <div class="search-box">
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="Batch No" name="search[batch_no]"
     class="demoInputBox" value="<?php echo $batch_no; ?>"  />
            <br/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="RFID Chip No"
    name="search[rfid_chip_no]" class="demoInputBox" value="<?php echo
    $rfid_chip_no; ?>"  />
            <input type="submit" name="go" class="btnSearch" value="Search">
            <input type="reset" class="btnSearch" value="Reset"
  onclick="window.location=''"></p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

here is the code search query and display data code:

```
<?php
    function perpage($count, $per_page = '10',$href) {
        $output = '';
        $paging_id = "link_perpage_box";
        if(!isset($_POST["page"])) $_POST["page"] = 1;
        if($per_page != 0)
        $pages  = ceil($count/$per_page);
        if($pages>1) {

            if(($_POST["page"]-3)>0) {
                if($_POST["page"] == 1)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=1 class="current-page">1</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="submit" name="page" class="perpage-link" value="1" />';
            }
            if(($_POST["page"]-3)>1) {
                    $output = $output . '...';
            }

            for($i=($_POST["page"]-2); $i<=($_POST["page"]+2); $i++)    {
                if($i<1) continue;
                if($i>$pages) break;
                if($_POST["page"] == $i)
                    $output = $output . '<span id='.$i.' class="current-page" >'.$i.'</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="submit" name="page" class="perpage-link" value="' . $i . '" />';
            }

            if(($pages-($_POST["page"]+2))>1) {
                $output = $output . '...';
            }
            if(($pages-($_POST["page"]+2))>0) {
                if($_POST["page"] == $pages)
                    $output = $output . '<span id=' . ($pages) .' class="current-page">' . ($pages) .'</span>';
                else                
                    $output = $output . '<input type="submit" name="page" class="perpage-link" value="' . $pages . '" />';
            }

        }
        return $output;
    }

    function showperpage($sql, $per_page = 10, $href) {
        $result  = mysql_query($sql);
        $count   = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $perpage = perpage($count, $per_page,$href);
        return $perpage;
    }
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
 <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="">
            <div class="search-box">
            <p><input type="text" placeholder="Batch No" name="search[batch_no]" class="demoInputBox" value="<?php echo $batch_no; ?>"  />
                <br/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="RFID Chip No" name="search[rfid_chip_no]" class="demoInputBox" value="<?php echo $rfid_chip_no; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="go" class="btnSearch" value="Search">
                <input type="reset" class="btnSearch" value="Reset" onclick="window.location=''"></p>
                </div>
            </form> 

            <h2>Search Result</h2>

            <?php

    $category = "";
    $code = "";

    $queryCondition = "";
    if(!empty($_POST["search"])) {
        foreach($_POST["search"] as $k=>$v){
            if(!empty($v)) {

                $queryCases = array("category","code");
                if(in_array($k,$queryCases)) {
                    if(!empty($queryCondition)) {
                        $queryCondition .= " AND ";
                    } else {
                        $queryCondition .= " WHERE ";
                    }
                }
                switch($k) {
                    case "category":
                        $category = $v;
                        $queryCondition .= "category LIKE '" . $v . "%'";
                        break;
                    case "code":
                        $code = $v;
                        $queryCondition .= "code LIKE '" . $v . "%'";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $orderby = " ORDER BY id desc"; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM toy " . $queryCondition;
    $href = 'index.php';                    

    $perPage = 2; 
    $page = 1;
    if(isset($_POST['page'])){
        $page = $_POST['page'];
    }
    $start = ($page-1)*$perPage;
    if($start < 0) $start = 0;

    $query =  $sql . $orderby .  " limit " . $start . "," . $perPage; 
    $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);

    if(!empty($result)) {
        $result["perpage"] = showperpage($sql, $perPage, $href);
    }
?>
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Search Result</title>
    </head><?php 
    if (empty($result)) {
   echo "<p>No results matched. Please try again..</p>\n";
} else {
?>

<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
                <?php
                        foreach($result as $k=>$v) {
                        if(is_numeric($k)) {
                    ?>
        <thead>
                    <tr>
          <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                        <td><?php echo $result[$k]["name"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
          <th><strong>Code</strong></th> 
                 <td><?php echo $result[$k]["code"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
          <th><strong>Category</strong></th>
                <td><?php echo $result[$k]["category"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

          <tr>


                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                    if(isset($result["perpage"])) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" align=right> <?php echo $result["perpage"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php }
    }?>
                <tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: WP doesn't have a fishsearch table by default, are you trying to interact with a 3rd party plugin? How far does the code get before it fails? Your linked code also appears to be incomplete, it's not clear how it fits into your theme or which template file it's in

Comment: ya i have to search for two matching field in a third party table.

https://pastebin.com/1gGGc989.. here is the full code..

Answer (score 0):

The text input names don't match the $_POST keys you are looping. Using [] in the input name attribute is for handling multiple inputs, not multiple keys.

Try replacing `name="search[batch_no]"` and `name="search[rfid_chip_no]"` with simply `name="search_batch_no"` and `name="search_rfid_chip_no"` and looping `$_POST` instead of `$_POST["search"]`.

Also you need to check the conditions match, as only `code` and `category` are matched in your input processing, there is no sign of `batch_no` or `rfid_chip_no`, so I have no idea how it could be 'working locally' unless it is simply selecting all records locally because the query condition is ignored.

Comment: it is not working also..how should i do it? i am helpless wasted days figuring this one..please help me...

Comment: post the updated code you have, it's a mystery to me how code and category match up to the search inputs? where are the values coming from/stored?